# Finding atmospheric pressure using temperature of boiling water

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, everyday-life, water

I was checking the temperature inside my oven using a multimeter with a temperature probe.  I had set the oven's thermostat to 190<sup>o</sup> C, and it had reached equilibrium, but the measured temperature was well below what I had set the thermostat for.  Having not previously used this temperature probe (new meter!), I was wondering if my probe and multimeter were accurate.  So I put a pot of water on to boil, to see how close it would be to 100<sup>o</sup> C.  The boiling water turned out to be 98<sup>o</sup> C.  This made me reasonably sure that my oven's thermostat was either wildly out of kilter, or incapable of heating to the desired temperature.  So I baked the item longer than the recipe called for.  Problem solved, except for wondering why the water was boiling at 98<sup>o</sup>C instead of 100<sup>o</sup>C.

I figured that it must have something to do with atmospheric pressure, and is probably also wrapped up with the elevation of my house above sea level.  The question I have, then, is this: is there a way to calculate the atmospheric pressure from the temperature I measured, or alternatively, determine what the boiling point of water should be at this moment -- to determine how accurate my meter is?  My house is 25 m above mean sea level, and the current atmospheric pressure is 1040 hPa.

Comment: Check here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boiling_point#Saturation_temperature_and_pressure

Comment: Thermocouples, especially simple ones on multimeters without temperature stabilised junctions are typically only good to 1-2deg C

Comment: Water has to be at a full, rolling boil in order to be at 100 ˚C. If you measured the water temperature while it was boiling at a level less than that, then that would explain why you measured 98 ˚C. Another possibility is that, as Martin wrote, your multimeter's probe may not have been accurate enough in this temperature range. I use food thermometer with a small probe tip which is designed for high accuracy in the room-temperature to 100 ˚C range. It consistently agrees with the temperature of the water in my sous vide water bath cooking device within 0.5 ˚C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steam Table says that the saturation temperature for Water @1040 hPa is 100.7°C. Conversely, the saturation pressure at 98°C is 943.9 hPa.
[Saturated Steam Table](http://www.efunda.com/materials/water/steamtable_sat.cfm)

Check the accuracy of your temperature probe as well as that of your barometer.

For the connection of Temperature, Pressure and Elevation, see [Barometric formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometric_formula)